# Rails, Bootstrap, and FullPage.js navbar navigation only works from first section

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, fullpage.js

I have a rails 5 app, which uses both bootstrap 4 and fullPage.js (for which I've disabled turbolinks). I have a bootstrap navbar which contains links to a couple different sections on the main page. This works, so long as the currently displayed section is the first one. If I scroll or click a link to a different section, all the links in the navbar somehow become disabled

Any idea how this is happening?

Here is my navbar (I know that I have a path to an "outside" route in logging out, but I don't think that should cause this problem):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse" id="menu" role="navigation">
    <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="#firstPage">My Brand</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <% if user_signed_in? %>
                <li data-menuanchor="firstPage" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#firstPage">Link One</a></li>
                <li data-menuanchor="secondPage" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#secondPage">Link Two</a></li>
                <li data-menuanchor="thirdPage" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#thirdPage">Link Three</a></li>
                <li data-menuanchor="fourthPage" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#fourthPage">Link Four</a></li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <li class="nav-item navbar-right">
                <%= link_to 'Log Out', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete, :class => 'nav-link'%>     
            </li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The fullPage.js initialization in application.js (really simple):

```
//= require jquery
//= require tether
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require fullpage
//= require_tree .

$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("Page Loaded")
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        anchors:['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage', 'fourthPage'],
    });
});
```

And finally, the actual sections:

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section" data-anchor="firstPage">
        <div class="container-fluid draw-border">
            Some Content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section" data-anchor="secondPage">Section 2</div>
    <div class="section" data-anchor="thirdPage">Section 3</div>
    <div class="section" data-anchor="fourthPage">Section 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a reproduction of it with a link.

Comment: Ok, sorry this took me a few days: I've forked the git repo and created a new heroku app. You can find the heroku app at https://protected-thicket-32363.herokuapp.com/ and the git repo at https://github.com/clintondix/FullpageBootstrapRails

Comment: Opening the home page should illustrate what I'm talking about - when you scroll/click to links referring to sections other than the first one, I can no longer click on the links. The relevant pages are in views/main_page and views/layouts, specifically the ones named with not_logged_in...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the css property `z-index` for your menu to place it over any other layer:

```
.bg-inverse{
    z-index: 999;
}
```